# Canvas displayed in gameView but not in build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was testing the build settings for my project that got a Main UI canvas which is displaying some objects, and when the mouse is on the current object, a copy of it is instantiated in an above canvas (well in the editor it's under the other canvases, so in real view it's above all), with a layer above all other like this:

```
zoomCard = Instantiate(gameObject, new Vector2(980, 750), Quaternion.identity);

    zoomCard.transform.SetParent(ZCanvas.transform, false);
  zoomCard.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Zoom");
   

  //adds a zoom  
   RectTransform rect = zoomCard.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
   rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(260, 399);
```

So in game View everything works fine.

But as soon as I build it in html5, the zoomed card never shows. I tried with safari, Chrome, and Firefox, same thing.
So I tried to build it in Mac executable too : same thing.

How can I possibly debug this? As on my game view render I have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I've found in other posts that, when unity crashes or when you update your project into a new version (my case).
Unity does not import some shaders for some given classes with no reason.

The workaround that worked for me was this one:

Browse to the folder/directory of your project.
Delete the Project Settings Folder.
You'll need to re import the scenes in your build, and evertything will work as it should